# How do I use Glass fish server with eclipse luna for Java EE?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

I thought that Glass Fish server came with Eclipse when you install the Glass fish tools for Java EE.  However, after trying to install the Glass fish tools, it said there was nothing to update.  Ok, so when I try to start the server, it asks for the server root.  Does the glass fish server come with Eclipse?  If so, how would I locate it?  Or if I need to install it on my computer, which I did, why does it not recognize the folder where I installed Glass fish server as a valid installation of Glass Fish Server?
Thanks in advance for any help,
Bruce

Comment: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-luna#.VFfuovmG8YE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the Glassfish4 and extract it. When adding glassfish server to the Eclipse locate the glassfish folder inside the Glassfish4 folder. And there you go. Eclipse EE doesn't come with any server, only with tools for EE development.

Answer (score 4):

After installing 'GlassFish Tools for Luna' from marketplace, get glassfish-4.0.zip, extract it (folder glassfish4 appeared). Select Window - Preferences - Server - Runtime Environment - Add..., select GlassFish4 - Next, specify Server Root as absolute path glassfish subfolder for glassfish4 folder that appeared after extract (like /home/(username)/glassfish4/glassfish - I use Xubuntu). Click Finish. Setup is completed.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are welcome to post solutions to problems that you believe others may have, but in order to do so please adhere to the Question-Answer format of the site. i.e. your initial post should be posed as a Question. You can then provide the solution in response by submitting, and accepting and Answer.

Comment: Funny thing is, answer marked correct doesn't answer the question. And here voidHead is complaining about the actual correct answer. Thanks Vitali, this helped me. Stick to solving problems. This is just more proof programmers are often glorified professional tinkerers.

Comment: before the time you said "select glassfish 4", we are asked what type of server it is, whatshould we do then?

Comment: This might need another question but how does one choose between the different Java EE servers or containers?  There is Tomcat, JBoss, GlassFish, etc.

Comment: Bruce Whealton what do you mean? You can choose any server or container. EJB jar, WAR and EAR work on servers, WAR file on containers.