# Glassfish Tools not Installing on Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I installed Glassfish tools using Eclipse Mars on Windows 7 64 bit. I am getting an error "The specified directory is not a valid GlassFish installation", mostly because I can't find the actual installation root. After installing it through the Marketplace it doesn't seem to be on my hard drive.

[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215552/the-specified-directory-is-not-a-valid-glassfish-installation) link suggests it should be on the top level of my C: drive, but it isn't there.

I tried to search for it, but searching my entire drive I only find C:\Program Files\eclipse\features\oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish_8.6.1.201603011333 which doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for and Eclipse agrees.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705071/root-path-glassfish-v4-eclipse-luna) work around, but that is for Java EE 7. Mars requires Java EE 8.

Some tutorials show a step in Eclipse where the server is installed in a folder of my creation, but that step never comes up.

Not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?